# PickMeUp date picker - disable array of dates

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using [PickMeUp](https://github.com/nazar-pc/PickMeUp) datepicker for selecting multiple dates. I would like to be able to pass an array of dates, disable these dates and display them in a different colour.

I currently only have the following code:

```
$('.multiple').pickmeup('clear');
$('.multiple').pickmeup({
    flat: true,
    mode: 'multiple'
});
```

If anyone knows how to do this, I would highly appreciate it.

Comment: Please provide more information to get help from community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is load the dates into an array. You can then check this array with `PickMeUp`'s [`object render event`](https://github.com/nazar-pc/PickMeUp#object-render-date) and check every date against the dates from the array. If any of the dates coincide, you simply return the object `disabled: true` and the user won't be able to select the dates.

Additionally, I also return the class `disabled` to improve the disabled dates' CSS colors. This because `PickMeUp`'s default color-scheme for disabled dates is black; this makes it hard to see them.

The following **Javascript/jQuery** achieves what you want:

```
// Creating some 'sample' dates 
var datesArray = [];
var d = new Date();
for (i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
    var tempDay = new Date(); tempDay.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    tempDay.setDate(d.getDate()+i);
    datesArray.push(tempDay.getTime());
}

$(function () {
    $('.multiple').pickmeup({
        flat: true,
        mode: 'multiple',
        // Before rendering each date, deselect dates if in the array
        render: function(date) {
            if ($.inArray(date.getTime(), datesArray) > -1){
                return {
                    disabled   : true,
                    class_name : 'disabled'
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
// Little hack to deselect current day: PickMeUp forces you to have a default date :(
$('.pmu-today').click();
```

With the following **CSS**:

```
.disabled {
    color: #5C5C8A !important;
    background: #000033;
}
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jsr8kxr8/)